# Invalid login: 535-5.7.8 Username and Password not accepted

Tags: node.js

while sending mail using modemailer with only few accounts it is working fine, but with some accounts, even though the credentials are correct, it is giving "Invalid login: 535-5.7.8 Username and Password not accepted. Learn more at
535 5.7.8  https://support.google.com/mail/?p=BadCredentials 3sm51852778pfg.186 - gsmtp"

Comment: Check carefully if all [account prerequisities](https://community.nodemailer.com/using-gmail/) are met.

Comment: Use TinyProxy on the machine with the modemailer and go to https://accounts.google.com/DisplayUnlockCaptcha using the proxy.
In this way GMail will remember the IP and allow SMTP access.
Also, enable Less-secure apps from https://myaccount.google.com/lesssecureapps

Comment: Yes, i enabled less secure apps, and it worked for me. :)

Answer (score 4):

Solution 1: It's the gmail security for less secure apps. Also a quick solution will be to turn off the access Allow less secure apps

Solution 2: Best way will be to work with 2-Step verification 2-Step Verification

Answer (score 0):

Solution post May 2022:

The issue you are having is related to googles remove [Less secure apps & your Google Account](https://support.google.com/accounts/answer/6010255?hl=en) setting from our google accounts.  Less secure apps was what enabled us to use our google login and passwords with their smtp server.

In order to use it now you must enable 2fa on your google account and configure an apps password.  You can then use the apps password in place of your actual google password to connect to the smtp server.

[Quick fix for SMTP username and password not accepted error](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Y_u5KIeXiVI)

Answer (score 0):

**Allow Less Secure Apps:**
Go to your Google account settings, navigate to "Security," and turn on "Less secure app access." Keep in mind that this method is less secure and should only be used if you cannot use 2FA.

**Generate an "App Password" (if available):**
If you don't see the "App Passwords" option in your Google account settings, try the following:

1. Go to your Google account settings.
2. Navigate to "Security."
3. If you see "App passwords," generate one for your application.

If the "App Passwords" option is not available, proceed with the "Less secure app access" method mentioned above.

Update Nodemailer Configuration:
Update your Nodemailer configuration to use the Gmail account details:

```
const mailConfig = {
  host: process.env.MAIL_HOST,
  port: 465,
  secure: true,
  auth: {
    user: process.env.MAIL_FROM,
    pass: process.env.MAIL_FROM_PASSWORD
  }
};
```

Ensure that `process.env.MAIL_FROM` and `process.env.MAIL_FROM_PASSWORD` contain your Gmail email address and the application-specific password or your account password if you are using the "Less secure app access" method.

**Use OAuth2 (Recommended):**
For a more secure approach, consider using OAuth2 for Gmail authentication with Nodemailer. This involves creating a project in the Google Developer Console and obtaining client credentials.

Here is an example of how you can configure Nodemailer with OAuth2:

```
const nodemailer = require('nodemailer');
const { google } = require('googleapis');

// Set up OAuth2 credentials
const oauth2Client = new google.auth.OAuth2(
  'YOUR_CLIENT_ID',
  'YOUR_CLIENT_SECRET',
  'YOUR_REDIRECT_URL'
);

oauth2Client.setCredentials({
  refresh_token: 'YOUR_REFRESH_TOKEN'
});

const accessToken = oauth2Client.getAccessToken();

// Nodemailer configuration
const mailConfig = {
  service: 'gmail',
  auth: {
    type: 'OAuth2',
    user: 'your.email@gmail.com',
    clientId: 'YOUR_CLIENT_ID',
    clientSecret: 'YOUR_CLIENT_SECRET',
    refreshToken: 'YOUR_REFRESH_TOKEN',
    accessToken: accessToken
  }
};

const transporter = nodemailer.createTransport(mailConfig);

// Send email
const mailOptions = {
  from: 'your.email@gmail.com',
  to: 'recipient@example.com',
  subject: 'Test email',
  text: 'This is a test email.'
};

transporter.sendMail(mailOptions, (error, info) => {
  if (error) {
    console.error(error);
  } else {
    console.log('Email sent: ' + info.response);
  }
});
```

Replace placeholders like 'YOUR_CLIENT_ID', 'YOUR_CLIENT_SECRET', 'YOUR_REDIRECT_URL', and 'YOUR_REFRESH_TOKEN' with your actual values.